# How to select a specific pod instance for a service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. On this cluster, there is one Kubernetes StatefulSet that is responsible for receiving messages, persisting the messages, and scheduling the received messages and an application processor of type Deployment that has 3 instances (replicas), ​Here the App Processor POD is receiving multiple kinds of messages from Message Processor POD using REST calls. 
So finally I have

```
message-processor-0
```

and

```
app-processor-12345
app-processor-23456
app-processor-45567
```

Here my requirement is, I want to send particular types of messages to​ only one dedicated instance of the App Processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a deployment, that specific POD has no reliable network identity. A POD's name and IP address will change whenever it is killed and recreated.

You have two options. One is to create a brand-new deployment and service for that particular pod, so you can communicate with that pod using the newly created service.

Otherwise StatefulSets are another choice, as they have a persistent network identity regardless of whether the POD is killed or restarted.

The StatefulSet pods get fixed ordered names, which will be in the format $(statefulset name)-$(ordinal).

For example if your yaml looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testservice
  namespace: testnamespace
  labels:
    app: testapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: testapp
  namespace: testnamespace
spec:
  serviceName: testservice
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
```

The names of Pods will be testapp-0, testapp-1 and so on.

Then you can use:

`testapp-0.testservice.testnamespace.svc.cluster.local` for accessing Pod 0 of testapp StatetefulSet

For more information refer to: [StatefulSet Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could use here is a [Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for your `app-processor`.

Statefulsets have the capability of having unique names for each of its replicas, persisted on the restarts in the form of:

- app-processor-0
- app-processor-1
- app-processor-2

So, they keep a sticky identity that you could use to send specific messages to one dedicated instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response @RickMo If I change AppProcessor to StatefulSet and how can I send specific messages to one dedicated instance? Here is my try with a sample REST endpoint.

Using service name
===============
root@ubuntu:/# curl http://app-processor:25000/api/v2/services/helloworld
This is Hello world Endpoint..!!

Using pod name
=============
root@ubuntu:/# curl http://app-processor-0:25000/api/v2/services/helloworld
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nextgen-gw-0

So here while communicating with the POD name I am getting could not resolve the host.

Comment: You can use the label that Statefulset is creating automatically in the pod with the key `statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name` in the Service. You can check it here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-name-label

Comment: I don't understand your solution here. What is the use of adding an annotation to communicate with each other?

Comment: That label is added automatically by the Statefulset you don't have to do anything. What I meant is that thanks to that label, you can you use it directly to access it throughout the service in the form `app-processor-0.service_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`